# Translation of application

Tags: c++, linux, language-translation

I'm creating a dictionary app, that downloads a translated page (from an online dictionary) and searches for translations. I have trouble with making a translated interface. I've made sepatate files, for exemple `string-en.hpp`, or `string.fr.hpp`. I also have a configuration file `lang` in a hidden directory in home folder (for now it could be `~/.dictionary/lang`). I don't know how to define (or include) for exemple `#define langEN` (or `#include "string-en.hpp"`) depending on content of `~/.dictionary/lang`.

That application is written for Linux, without any graphic library.

How to do that?

Comment: Follow the lead of Java, locale, and resource bundles.

Comment: Have a look at catopen, catgets and catclose.  It is locale based probably does what you want without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Can't you include both and get the one you need after checking `lang` ?

Comment: @duffymo: Java appeared in 1995. Unix had a localization library in 1990 (written, ironically, by Sun).

Comment: @n.m. thanks for the info.  No irony needed - Sun was a driver behind Unix.